# Values To Column Headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database for our students where we store questions and responses in it. I am trying to build a report on it. There is a question table, and a response table. Both of these tables have a common field, QuizNo. The table structure is similar as follows:

Quiz Table:

```
QuizNo |   Status
  1       Reviewed
  2       Not Reviewed
```

Quiz Response Table:

```
QuizNo  | QuestionID | Response
1             11         Yes
2             13         No
2             11         Yes
1             13         No
```

The expected result from the query would contain the amount of rows in the Quiz table, in this case 2. Each of the questions ID's and their responses would form a new column, in the same row.

The tabular data being return would look like the following:

```
                  (11 and 13 are question ID's)

QuizNo  |  Status     |   11   |    13
  1        Reviewed       Yes       No
  2        Not Reviewed   Yes       No
```

I have tried a few different things, but I can't get the column headers to turn into the question ID's with the responses.

TIA!

Comment: You'll want to PIVOT the values of your `QuestionID` into columns, the duplicate has several examples on how to do this.

Comment: the duplicate is showing how to transform all the select to columns, I am only trying to transform a subset...

Comment: You only transform the columns that you need in this case the question id.  In your case the code would be similar to `pivot( max(Response) for questionid in ([11], [13]))`

Comment: So I have to hardcode per question ID?

Comment: If you have a few then yes, if not then you'd use dynamic sql which also is explained in the duplicate.